# Excel VBA: How do I format just certain words within a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have not yet got my head around VBA other than recording Macros.

Could anyone talk me through how to edit just some text within a cell? I have a cell (Y2) filled with text but I want just "University of" to stand out (either in a different colour or by making it bold).

Because I'm an absolute novice to VBA, please can your answer be literally from opening VBA editor.

Thank you so much community!

Answer (score 2):

Try this mate. Put this into vba:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("Y2").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=13).Font.FontStyle = Bold
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys

I'm just posting my final solution for those who are interested. The following makes specific text in a cell red.

```
Public Sub HighlightCodes2()
  ' Select Cells to be highlighted and Run this Sub.
  Dim Codes(1)
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim StartPos As Long
  Codes(1) = "Univ Cape Town"

  For Each Rng In Selection.Cells
    For i = 1
       StartPos = InStr(Rng.Value, Codes(i))
       If StartPos > 0 Then Rng.Characters(StartPos, Len(Codes(i))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    Next i
  Next Rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have not yet got my head around VBA other than recording Macros

Recording macros is a great way to learn how to use VBA to manipulate the Excel object model.

Try recording a macro, then while it's recording, make the changes you want (e.g. format some characters in the cell bold).

The recorded macro will contain code that you can study and adapt.